# How to store terms to search on those terms in the ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene

I have a requirement where the search should be made on some specific terms. For example,

```
{
   "_index":"idx_name",
   "_type":"_doc",
   "_id":"82000223323",
   "_score":1,
   "_source":{
      "title":"where is my card?"
   }
}
```

Assuming the above document is in Elasticsearch, I need to fetch this document whenever there is a query on either `debit` or `credit` keywords. So, How do I go about solving this in ES? What would be the mapping for that new field and what would be the right query?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new field called card_type to index types debit and/or credit.

So, you can use [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) to filter results by each type.

Mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "card_type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST my-index-000001/_doc  
{
  "title": "where is my card?",
  "card_type": "debit"
}

OR

POST my-index-000001/_doc  
{
  "title": "any value here",
  "card_type": ["debit", "credit"]
}
```

The new query filter by type debit.

```
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
   "query": {
     "bool": {
       "filter": [
         {
           "term": {
             "card_type": "debit"
           }
         }
       ],
       "must": [
         {
           "match": {
             "title": "where is my card?"
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
}
```